# Порядок инициализации класса (конструкторов) родителя и наследника при нескольких конструкторах в обоих классах

Tags: java, конструктор

Нашла следующий порядок инициализации объекта для случая наследования классов:

- Статические поля класса Parent;
- Статический блок инициализации класса Parent;
- Статические поля класса Сhild;
- Статический блок инициализации класса Child;
- Нестатические поля  класса Parent;
- Нестатический блок инициализации класса Parent;
- Конструктор класса Parent;
- Нестатические поля  класса Сhild;
- Нестатический блок инициализации класса Сhild
- Конструктор класса Сhild.

Но что делать, если несколько конструкторов и в родителе, и в наследнике - каким образом они загружаются? Все конструкторы родителя, а потом наследника или по одному в порядке написания?

На собеседовании мне показали пример возможной ошибки в конструкторе (или его исполнения - точно не помню) наследника из-за порядка конструкторов родителя, но я не могу найти нигде внятной информации и примеров такой ситуации в коде. Можете разъяснить этот момент?

Comment: То что Вы написали конечно здорово, но хотелось бы знать какая платформа/язык?

Comment: Извините, Java, ))

Comment: "все конструкторы родителя" ??? - выполняется только тот конструктор, который вызывается в коде. Если один конструктор вызывает другой, то в этой цепочке все однозначно.

Comment: вы можете показать пример использования/взаимодействия конструкторов родителя и наследника, при котором возникнет исключительная ситуация?

Comment: В знаете в каких случаях может возникнуть исключение при использовании конструкторов наследником родителя ? (имеет отношение к порядку загрузки классов и их элементов)

Comment: вам же на собеседовании показали, зачем еще нам показывать? :) Проблемы могут возникнуть, если конструктор родителя вызывает переопределяемый метод. Тогда, если метод переопределен в потомке и обращается к каким-то полям потомка, эти поля не будут инициализированы на момент вызова.

Comment: я не помню этого примера и пояснения, если бы помнила - не было бы вопроса.)))
zRrr, а про ваш вариант проблемы спасибо, очень интересно

Answer (score 9, accepted):

В классе-наследнике вызывается один конструктор родителя.
Либо конструктор родителя вызывается явно в начале конструктора наследника с помощью конструкции `super`, либо вызывается неявно при подстановке `super();` в начало конструктора компилятором. При этом если у родителя нет конструктора без аргументов, то код приведёт к ошибке компиляции.
[Документация по этому поводу](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html).

Таким образом, нет неопределённости с тем, сколько конструкторов родителя и какие именно вызываются в потомке.

Проблемы из-за порядка вызова конструкторов и инициализации полей классов могут возникнуть, как писал @zRrr, если в конструкторе родителя вызывается переопределяемый или реализуемый потомком метод, который в свою очередь использует ещё не инициализированные поля потомка.
Пример:

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    private final String fullName;

    protected Animal()
    {
        fullName = "Animal " + getName();
    }

    public String getFullName()
    {
        return fullName;
    }

    protected abstract String getName();
}

public class Dog extends Animal
{
    private String thisName = "DDog";

    protected String getName()
    {
        return thisName;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Animal animal = new Dog();
    System.out.println(animal.getFullName());
}
```

На экран будет выведено `Animal null`, так как на момент вызова метода `getName` у `Dog` поле `thisName` ещё не инициализировано.
При создании `animal` происходит вызов конструктора по умолчанию у `Dog`, который приводит сначала к вызову конструктора без параметров у `Animal`, а только затем к инициализации поля `thisName`.

---

Ещё есть такой пример, взятый из [этой статьи](https://dzone.com/articles/java-object-initialization):

```
public class Upper
{
    String upperString;

    public Upper()
    {
        Initializer.initialize(this);
    }
}

public class Lower extends Upper
{
    String lowerString = null;

    public Lower()
    {
        super();
        System.out.println("Upper:  " + upperString);
        System.out.println("Lower:  " + lowerString);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        new Lower();
    }
}

public class Initializer
{
    static void initialize(final Upper anUpper)
    {
        if (anUpper instanceof Lower)
        {
            Lower lower = (Lower)anUpper;
            lower.lowerString = "lowerInited";
        }
        anUpper.upperString = "upperInited";
    }
}
```

На экран будет выведено:

```
Upper:  upperInited
Lower:  null;
```

Но если заменить `String lowerString = null;` на `String lowerString;`, то вывод будет:

```
Upper:  upperInited
Lower:  lowerInited
```

Проблема в первоначальном варианте в том, что присваивание `null` в `String lowerString = null;` происходит после вызова конструктора родителя, в котором в свою очередь вызывается метод `Initializer.initialize`. То есть в `lowerString` сначала записывается `"lowerInited"`, а затем `null`.

---

Оба примера демонстрируют проблемы, возникающие из-за неправильных предположений о порядке выполнения кода. Сложность осознания того, что за чем выполняется в данном коде, сама по себе уже говорит о том, что на практике код так писать не стоит.

Comment: Спасибо за такой развернутый ответ, сейчас буду разбираться, отпишусь позже.

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что в следующем примере будет ошибка компиляции?
`public class A
{
    public A(int a){   }
}
`
public class B extends A {
    public B()
    {    }
}

public class Main {
 public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
      B b =  new B();
    }
} 
`

Comment: @KatrinMayer да. Для воспроизведения ошибки компиляции даже класс `Main` в данном примере не нужен - достаточно `A` и `B`.

Comment: то есть наследование по факту накладывает на нас обязательства использовать конструктор родителя , даже если мы этого не хотим? 
и тут мы уже сами должны правильно и корректно обработать это обязательство?

Comment: @KatrinMayer да, накладывает обязательства. Ещё не нужно забывать, что если `A extends B`, а `B extends C`, а `C` - просто `C` (то есть неявно `extends Object`), то при создании `A` сначала выполняется конструктор для `Object`, потом для `C`, потом для `B`, а только потом для `A`. Это так называемая "цепочка конструкторов".

Comment: @KatrinMayer если есть ещё какие-то моменты для уточнения, которые не тянут на отдельный вопрос, - спрашивайте. Если же ответ вас устроил, то не забудьте отметить его как правильный (галочка слева от ответа).

Comment: нет - это все. Спасибо большое за такую полезную информацию. Мне очень помогло.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю такой порядок:

```
/**
 * Порядок инициализации таков:
 * [1]. Статические поля базового класса;
 * [2]. Статический блок инициализации базового класса;
 * [3]. Статические поля производного класса;
 * [4]. Статический блок инициализации производного класса;
 * [5]. Поля (Глобальные переменные) базового класса;
 * [6]. Нестатический блок инициализации базового класса;
 * [7]. Конструктор базового класса [если у родителя нет конструктора без аргументов, то код приведёт к ошибке компиляции];
 * [8]. Поля (Глобальные переменные)  производного класса;
 * [9]. Нестатический блок инициализации производного класса;
 * [10]. Конструктор производного класса;
 */

class Base {

    //[1] transient переменные и статические поля не сериализуются
    private static Base instance = new Base("))(("); //BASE = 0 //
    public static int _baseStaticInsect = 111; //сокрыто, доступ Base._baseStaticBase
    private static final int DELTA = 2;
    private static int BASE = 3;

    //[2]
    static {
        System.out.println("[static instance class initializer] " + Inherit.class.getSimpleName());
    }

    //[5]
    private int i = 5;
    protected int j; //mod:protected-internal
    int x;
    int internal; //mod:package
    public int iInc;

    //[6]
    {
        System.out.println("[instance class initializer] " + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }


    //[7]
    //private недоступен  из вне, нельзя создать без рефлексии
    //если у нет конструктора без аргументов или он приватный, то код приведёт к ошибке компиляции];
    public Base() {
        System.out.println("[constructor] " + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
        x = BASE + DELTA;
    }

    //[7]
    public Base(String data) {
        this();
        System.out.println("[constructor] (String)" + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
        System.out.println(data);

    }

    static int printInit(String s) {
        return -1;
    }
}

public class Inherit extends Base {

    //[3]
    public static int _baseStaticBase = 222;
    public static int _baseStaticInherit = 4;

    //[4]
    static {
        System.out.println("[static class initializer] " + Inherit.class.getSimpleName());
    }

    //[8]
    private int internal;

    public int Integnal() { //getInternal
        return this.internal;
    }

    private boolean internalFlag;

    public boolean isInternalFlag() {
        return internalFlag;
    }

    //[9]
    {
        System.out.println("[instance class initializer] Inherit " + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

    //[10]
    public Inherit() {
        this("start");
        System.out.println("Inherit constructor");
    }

    //[10]
    public Inherit(String data) {
        System.out.println("Inherit constructor data");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Base base = new Base();
        Inherit inherit = new Inherit();
    }

}
```